# Explanation of idiom "Can't sit on one's hair"

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

Reading a book by Salman Rushdie ("Shame") and there's such an expression, I guess it should be an idiom, but I can't find its explanation.

So, the author describes his younger sister.

> ...Who is twenty-two, and studying engineering in Karachi; who **can't sit on her hair any more**, and who (unlike me) is a Pakistani citizen

Thanks, for your help and time

Comment: Girls and women with long hair sometimes boast that it is so long they can sit on it, i.e. the ends more than touch the chair. Presumably the sister has had hers cut short now she is grown up?

Comment: It might also mean that she can't just sit at home but must actually be up and out doing something (like engineering).